# How can I rewrite this xquery to remove a subnode without rewriting this entire query?

Tags: xml, xquery

Here is the xquery that works on this xml files.

```
<results>
  {
    for $depen in doc("../company/dependent.xml")//dependent
    where $depen/dependent_name=*
    return
     <row>
     <dependent name="{$depen/dependent_name}"/>
      {
        for $emp in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee[ssn = $depen/essn ]
        return

        <employee>

        <emp fname="{$emp/fname}" lname="{$emp/lname}"/>
              {
              for $man in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee[ssn = $emp/superssn ]
              return
              <manager>

              <mgr fname="{$man/fname}" lname="{$man/lname}"/>             

              </manager>
             }              
        </employee> 
      } 
     </row>   
  }
</results>
```

It produces the output below.

```
<results>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Alice"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Elizabeth"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Michael"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Alice"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="James" lname="Borg"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Joy"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="James" lname="Borg"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Theodore"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="James" lname="Borg"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
  <row>
    <dependent name="Abner"/>
    <employee>
      <emp fname="Jennifer" lname="Wallace"/>
      <manager>
        <mgr fname="James" lname="Borg"/>
      </manager>
    </employee>
  </row>
</results>
```

How do I remove the employee and manager tags in the final result so it looks more like this below.

```
   <results>
      <row>
        <dependent name="Alice"/>
        <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <dependent name="Elizabeth"/>
        <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <dependent name="Michael"/>
        <emp fname="John" lname="Smith"/>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <dependent name="Alice"/>
        <emp fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
        <mgr fname="Franklin" lname="Wong"/>
      </row>
      <row>
```

... and so on and so forth.

I just need to know how to rewrite the final xquery to remove the need for employee and manager node in the final result but still keep the value.

Comment: Well, anywhere you do `return <employee>...</employee>` or `return <manager>...</manager>` you can simply use `return ...`, no? I am not sure I understand the problem, if your current XQuery code has literals for `employee` or `manager` elements then simply remove the literals from the code.

Comment: It gives me an error when I do this. Could you show me an example of how it would be done?

Comment: Which XQuery processor exactly do you use, which error message exactly do you get? And your original example seems to be lacking closing tag for the `emp` element.

Comment: I fixed the problem but could you help me with another problem. How do I remove the literals from this bit of code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718807/how-would-you-remove-all-literals-from-this-xquery